# What do I do if my sample for cross sections is not random in a panel regression model?

Tags: random-effects-model, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, mixed-model

I am trying to implement a panel regression model, but there is one issue: both fixed effects estimation (FE) and random effects estimation (RE) require that the cross section sample be random. For my situation this requirement has not been met (I selected each city based upon a particular characteristic). What can I do about this? I know that in experimental design there was a way of accounting for this (i.e. the Bonferroni, Scheffe, and Tukey comparisons), but is there something similar in panel regression? Would a "mixed" panel regression model be appropriate here?